# How to call Auth0 loginWithRedirect function in React useEffect without button clicking?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0

In React app, I was going to implement Auth0 login like the following.
When the user accesses the `/login`, it will check if the user is authenticated.

Here is the code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import SplashScreen from "src/components/SplashScreen";

const LoginView = () => {
  const { loginWithRedirect, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
  const history = useHistory();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      history.push("/explore");
    } else {
      loginWithRedirect();
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated])

  return <SplashScreen />;
};

export default LoginView;
```

But when I log in from the Auth0 login page, I am redirected to the `/login` page of the React app, and it falls in looping indefinitely.
I tried to log out the `isAuthenticated` value on the console like in the above code, but it is `false` even though I logged in on the Auth0 authentication page correctly.

Please let me know how I can solve this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is working.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import SplashScreen from "src/components/SplashScreen";

const LoginView = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();
  const history = useHistory();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function checkUser() {
      if (isAuthenticated) {
        await history.push("/explore");
      } else {
        loginWithRedirect();
      }
    }

    checkUser();                            // called async checkUser()
  }, [isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect]); // added loginWithRedirect

  return <SplashScreen />;
}

export default LoginView;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the below pattern source: https://thinkster.io/tutorials/auth0-react-login-and-user-profile/protect-the-profile-route

```
 const { loading, isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading || isAuthenticated) {
      return;
    }
    const fn = async () => {
      await loginWithRedirect({
        appState: { targetUrl: path }
      });
    };
    fn();
  }, [loading, isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect, path]);
```